# Connection problems with Python Remote Server and Robot Framework

Tags: python, windows-10, robotframework, xml-rpc, windows-firewall

We are trying to use the Robot Framework together with a Python Remote Server, so that libraries can be used, that are lying on a different machine.

Lets call the machine on which runs the Python Remote Server A giving me library libA, and the machine which calls libA using the Python Remote Server B. I need this settings, as only machine A has internet connection. Both machines are Windows 10 machines.

I was already successully calling a method in libA from the machine B and everything works as expected if I was logging in to machine B manually and start the on A manually.

Now, I was trying to do the same thing using jenkins, which a special jenkins User and I have connectivity problems. (So it shouldn't be a firewall issue)

```
Getting keyword names from library 'Remote' failed: 
Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_names' failed: 
Connecting remote server at http://192.168.0.1:8270 failed: 
[WinError 10061] No connection could be established, 
as target computer refuses connection
```

Does anyone knows, what might be the problem?

Comment: Are you have to access URL http://192.168.0.1:8270  through browser ? What it shows when you hit the URL from machine B using a browser ?

Comment: It is just not working in the jenkins job. If I'll perform the action as a normal user everything works as expected.

Comment: So you start the remote python server through Jenkins and than when you try to access the url manually than it works fine ?

Comment: @SariqShaikh: That is exactly my point.